# Проверка работы контейнера после запуска в docker-compose

Tags: bash, docker, тестирование, docker-compose

Хочу протестировать запустится ли приложение описанное в `docker-compose.yml` до его внедрения на сервер. Буду запускать скрипт проверки автоматически в `gitlab-runner` или `travis`.

Например, результат работы `docker-compose ps`

```
      Name                     Command              State          Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lemp_mysql_1        docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld     Up      3306/tcp
lemp_nginx_1        nginx -g daemon off;            Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
lemp_php_1          docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm   Up      9000/tcp
lemp_phpmyadmin_1   /run.sh phpmyadmin              Up      0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
```

Здесь, контейнер `php` должен считаться работающим и правильно запущеным если:

1. В колонке `State` значение `Up`
2. В колонке `Ports` значение `9000/tcp`

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать скрипт, результат которого можно передать в конструкцию вида

```
if [ <контейнер_не_запущен_или_запущен_не_правильно> ]; then
    echo "всё плохо"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: так же вы можете  запустить ваши интеграционные тесты напротив контейнера.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я не понял что вы имеете ввиду =( вы говорите о доступности контейнеров друг для друга?

Comment: я имею в виду, что у многих проектов есть интеграционные тесты, которые позволяют проверить правильность работы основной части проекта. их можно запустить напротив локального сервера, а можно напротив контейнера. если ошибок нет, то контейнеры правильно подняты.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я понял, матчастью я не владею. буду читать-изучать. спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(( $(docker ps --filter name=XXXX --filter status=running  --filter status=restarting | wc -l) == 1)) 
then
    echo "всё плохо"
    exit 1
fi
```

где XXXX - это имя контейнера

Comment: Это частично поможет! `XXXX` - это значение из колонки `Name` из результатов работы `docker-compose ps`. Спасибо. А зачем фильтровать по статусу два раза `--filter status=running  --filter status=restarting` ?

Comment: restarting  не означает. что контейнер не рабочий. контейнер может стартовать еще. можно убрать это, если нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получился такой скрипт

```
SERVICES=(mysql php)
PORTS=(3306/tcp 9000/tcp)

for (( i=0; i<${#SERVICES[@]}; i++ )) do
    ID=$(docker-compose ps -q ${SERVICES[$i]})
    PORT=$(docker ps --filter id=$ID --filter status=running --format "{{.Ports}}")

    if [ ! $PORT ] || [ $PORT != ${PORTS[$i]} ]; then
        docker-compose logs ${SERVICES[$i]}
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Спасибо @SeniorPomidor за наводку